# Setting up AWS-SDK (boto) on a Mac for PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, pycharm, boto

I'm new to Python and PyCharm, but have used a Mac and AWS for a number of years.  I have written a few simple Python scripts on my Mac using PyCharm CE and these also work when ported to my windows servers.

What I'm unsure is how to configure / import the `boto-2.29.1` library so its available in PyCharm. I have downloaded and extracted to my home folder and also add to my PATH. I see references to `PYTHONPATH` but can see where to update this.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions? https://github.com/boto/boto#installation - specifically if you downloaded the zip, have you run `python setup.py install`?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I had tried this but it wants to write to python 2.7 library folder.  When I installed PyCharm I have selected 3.4.  Will this matter?

Comment: Yes, Python modules are specific to the version they are installed against. If you have installed Python 3.4, you could try something like `python3.4 setup.py install`, however I'm not sure if boto is Python 3.x compatible at the moment. There is a Python 3 branch (https://github.com/boto/boto3) but it is listed as unstable. I would recommend sticking with Python 2.7 for now if possible.

Comment: arhhh, thanks I now see on http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforpython/ that v3 support is a developer preview.  I will change my interpreter in PyCharm back to 2.7 and see how I get on.  Rob

Comment: In module settings, look for sdk setting.  Specify the python interpeter of your choice. ie. 3.3 or 2.7.  Remove the java jdk reference which is possibly installed by default.  This will at least enable you to run and debug the code, but it will not fix the problem with code completion.  As for that part I am still figuring it out.